# Does Oracle Database delete all the memory on restart?

Tags: oracle, database-administration, oracle19c

When we restart an Oracle database instance, does it delete all the data in the memory and kick a fresh start, or keep some information in the memory?

Comment: [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/oracle-database-instance.html#GUID-425B8CA6-73A1-47A0-972C-2D0802A57DE5) sort of covers this; but why do you ask? Are you having an issue that you think is related to startup/shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All memory that the instance had is cleared. In a RAC database that has multiple instances running, restarting one instance does not clear the memory from other instances.